# Post parameters through a form, to create a URL based on said parameters

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes, parameter-passing

Within a form, a user can search and select within 2 drop downs (city and town, for example). Once they submit the form, I want that to redirect to a URL with the chosen dropdown options in the URL.

So, upon form submission, they will be redirected to www.domain.co.uk/city/town.

I'm struggling to get to grips with the concept of URL parameters, and how to pass them to the route!

**Current set up:**

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['search'], 'method' => 'POST', 'id' => 'search']) !!}
```

The two fields of which I want to post to the URL are:

```
<input type="hidden" name="town" id="town">
```

and

```
{!! Form::select('city', $city, null, 
    ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'city', 'required']) 
!!}
```

I'm aware I'll have to post the ID of the latter, and so I'll have to look up the actual `name` field within the DB and return it to use (I have to generate the slug anyways).

**Route**:

```
Route::post('{city}/{town}', ['uses' => 'Controller@search',
        'city' => Input::get('city'), 'town' => Input::get('town')]
)->name('search');
```

**Controller:**

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    return view('location.search');
}
```

How can I use the two fields' values within the URL when they're redirected? I think I'm approaching it the wrong way but I can't think of alternatives.

Any help would be massively appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change your route structure to something like:

```
Route::post('search', 'Controller@search')->name('search');
Route::get('{city}/{town}', 'Controller@show')->name('location.show');
```

And in your controller:

```
public function show(Request $request, $city, $town) {
    // Do something with $city & $town
    return view('location.show');
}

public function search(Request $request) {
    $input = $request->only('city', 'town');
    // TODO: validate the input
    return redirect()->route('location.show', $input);
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you very much - you've saved me from a night of no sleep.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your data to be available in url, your `Route` should be for a `get` request. Not a `post`.

```
Route::get('{city}/{town}', 'Controller@search');
```

Then, in your controller you can get them simply by adding them in your parameters list:

```
public function search($city, $town)
```

Comment: No, I want to use those variables inside the URL. So for example, if they choose Texas (town) and France (city) in the dropdowns, once they submit the form, the URL is displayed as - www.domain.co.uk/france/texas. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: So your Route should be a get one.

Answer (score 0):

How about we take another approach and use javascript without the form. An example as follows:

```
<input type="hidden" name="town" id="town" value="town">

<select name="city" id="city">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="City1">City 1</option>
    <option value="City2">City 2</option>
    <option value="City3">City 3</option>
    <option value="City4">City 4</option>
</select>
<button type="button" onclick="redirect()">Redirect</button>
<script>
    function redirect(){
        var city = document.querySelector('#city').value;
        var town = document.querySelector('#town').value;
        if(city != '' && town != ''){
            window.location = 'http://mydomain.co.ke/'+city+'/'+town;
            //or
            window.location = '/'+city+'/'+town;
        }
        else{
            alert('Select a city');
        }
    }
</script>
```

As a note the input/select elements can still be created using the Form Facade